# Adding multiple bids for each tokenId

Tags: solidity, nft

I am making a test biding system in solidity, and I have a problem. I want to make a list of bids for each tokenId.

```
struct Bid {
        bool hasBid;
        uint tokenId1;
        address bidder;
        uint value;
    }

    
    mapping (uint => Bid) public Bids; 

function enterBidForNFT(uint Index, value) public virtual  {
        Bids[Index] = Bid(true, Index, msg.sender, value);
    }
```

There are implementations where only the highest bid is stored, but I want all of the bids to be available and their corresponding addresses.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can update your mapping to:

```
mapping (uint => Bid[]) public Bids;
```

and you don't need to have tokenId agian in your `Bid` struct when you have defined it in the mapping, for adding new bids your code should look like this:

```
Bids[tokenId].push(Bid(hasBid,bidder,value));
```

and you can also have mapping for highestBidder so you can get track of who is the highest bidder and  you can override it if new higher bid exist

```
struct HighestBid{uint256 value,address bidder};
    // tokenId -> highest bidder
mapping(uin256 => HighestBid) public highestBidder;
```